# Magento does not show template

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, template

I can't figure out why magento is not loading my template:

[image]

The template is located at `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/fekete/Newsletter2Go/customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml`

I double checked its existence. It does exist on the server.

I executed these two commands to make sure that the permissions are correct:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

then I ran

```
chown -R myuser:www *
```

from the project root. I also cleared the cache. Nothing happens.

I also removed the content from the template and replaced it by this:

```
Test Test Test
```

But nothing shows at all even though the template hints reveal that it should render.

**UPDATE:**

I found this in the log

> Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/fekete/Newsletter2Go/customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml
>   Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/fekete/Newsletter2Go/showOnAllPages.phtml

Comment: the path shown in the template path hints and mentioned in the question are the same. Are you sure, you have mentioned the correct path of your file in the question?

Comment: Yes of course they are the same. I try to load `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/fekete/Newsletter2Go/customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml` but nothing shows. I already checked if it does exist on the server under this path and it does.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by allowing symlinks. I used [n98-magerun](https://n98-magerun.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to solve it

```
./n98-magerun.phar config:set dev/template/allow_symlink 1
```